# Twitter Integrations In Flutter

Tags: flutter, twitter

I have integrate Twitter Login in my flutter App. I have integrated it by using flutter_twitter plugin.
But This is giving me User Name only. But I Want to get user Image and Email Id also.
How Can I get User Profile Details?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that when you authenticate like here:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter/example

You do not get more info about yourself? At that point you provided so much info about your token that you probably know your other details, it looks to me that the plugin is mainly meant to be used for tweeting and not fetching infomation about Twitter users.

However, you have the key+secret, so you could make your own calls to the twitter API directly and fetch more information when existing plugins do not do as much as you want

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/callback-urls

Or if you want to ask the plugin author for enhancement, then feel free to do so on the GitHub:

https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login

Comment: Thanks, Lemme try @Anton Krug